# It will not insert if the value of the 2 table are the same

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My problem is , I want to make an Enrollment System that will not insert the value if the time is conflict for example

I have a two table which is Enlistment and Subject. This is for Enlistment

[image: Enlistment]

Table : Subject
[image]

Now my Problem is if I inserted a value which will conflict the time and days, my program will just Insert it , and not give an error The schedule cannot be inserted cause of conflict and that is my problem.

This is the possible Output that I want:

I will insert a value in Enlistment example: 
48490000, 48490000, 103, 8:00 - 9:30 AM, MWF

now this will create an error which is cannot insert conflict schedule and it will now allow it and this is my code

```
string offerNo = "", capacity = "", offNo = "" , time = "", day = "";
        string a = "", b = "";

        conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.offerNo from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.offerNo ='" + textEnrollOfferNo.Text + "' AND a.studID = '" + textEnrollID.Text + "'", conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            offerNo = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        dr.Dispose();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.time, a.days from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.studID = '" + textEnrollID.Text + "'", conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            time = dr[0].ToString();
            day = dr[1].ToString();
        }
        dr.Dispose();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select offerNo,capacity,days,time from Subject  where offerNo ='" + textEnrollOfferNo.Text +  "'", conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            offNo = dr[0].ToString();
            capacity = dr[1].ToString();
            a = dr[2].ToString();
            b = dr[3].ToString();
        }
        dr.Dispose();

        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        if (textEnrollOfferNo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input Offer No.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if (textEnrollOfferNo.Text == offerNo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert duplicate schedules", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if (offNo != textEnrollOfferNo.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Offer No doesn't exist!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if (textEnrollOfferNo.Text == offNo && Convert.ToInt32(capacity) == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Subject is closed!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if ((a == day && b == time) || (day == a && time == b))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The schedule is conflict!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textEnrollOfferNo.Clear();
            textEnrollOfferNo.Focus();
        }
        else if ((textEnrollOfferNo.Text != offerNo && a != day && b != time) || (textEnrollOfferNo.Text != offerNo && a == day && b != time) || (textEnrollOfferNo.Text != offerNo && a != day && b == time))
        {
            //Button Add Subject for Student
            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("AddSubject", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@enlistID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textEnrollID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textEnrollID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@offerNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textEnrollOfferNo.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();

            MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully! ", "SUCCESS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.offerNo,b.subj,b.description,b.units,b.room,b.days,b.time from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.studID ='" + textEnrollID.Text + "'", conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[6], dr[4], dr[5]);
            }
            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select sum(b.units) from Enlistment a, Subject b where a.offerNo = b.offerNo AND a.studID ='" + textEnrollID.Text + "'", conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                textTotalUnits.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            }
            dr.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        dr.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: You need to add a unique key constraint in the table for columns you don't want duplicates inserted to

Comment: I think it's not about duplicates but about differing times between offer 103 in subject and offer 103 in enlistent, no?

Comment: Have you tried checking the NOT EXISTS(...)  clause in the WHERE to check for overlapping periods?

Comment: @Tyron78 For example, In my Enlistment table I dont have 103,8:00 - 9:00 AM , MWF then if I inserted it to the Enlistment it will create an error because in my Enlistment I already have the same time a days which is 101, 8:00 - 9:00 AM, MWF now that is my problem, my code will just Insert it and It will not display a message that the schedule is conflict

Comment: @p.marino Ohh, not yet can you show me, thanks if it is ok

Comment: @p.marino I think, you have a point, let me try it, thanks for the advice by the way, I didn't think about that

Comment: EXISTS()  is used specifically to ensure that a separate (but logically connected) subquery holds true as a precondition to the main query. And of course it can be negated with NOT. I think  it is a good fit for your case.

Comment: @p.marino can you show me sir, on how to do it, I dont have any Idea on how start it

Comment: something like INSERT (X,Y,Z) INTO TABLE1 A WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE2 B WHERE B.F = A.F AND B.START_DATE = A.START DATE) - I cannot be more specific because I am at work and can't devote much time to this, sorry.

Comment: @p.marino its ok sir, I can understand your point, and thanks by the way

Comment: Can you change you table design?  It would be much easier, if you had StartTime and EndTime as two separate columns

Comment: @JonathanWillcock yeah sure, can you give me some source code , for the result sir? A big thanks if it is okay!

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/ Also, you should use aliases that have some relevance instead of a, b, c....https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: I would also urge to look at your tables, you have some pretty serious design issues going on. Instead of storing start and end time as single string you should have two columns and use the time datatype instead of strings. Your days column is even more challenging as it violates 1NF by storing multiple values in a single tuple. With a better data model the challenge you are facing with scheduling would be easy to work with. Since the data model is challenging, the queries are incredibly difficult.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry sir, Im just exhausted while coding, that's why I use some variable that is not appropriate, because I can't solve my problem

Comment: I would suggest using ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older ANSI-89 style. They have been available for over 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins I understand your challenges here and I can help. Could you post the table definition and some sample data? Here is a great place that explains how to post this. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have access to SQL Server Management Studio?  If so, open a New Query window and paste the following in:

```
declare @enlistment table
(
EnlistID int,
StudID int,
OfferNo int,
StartTime datetime,
EndTime datetime,
StudDays varchar(3)
)
insert into @enlistment VALUES
(48490000, 48490000, 101, '08:00:00', '09:00:00', 'MWF'),
(48490000, 48490000, 102, '08:00:00', '09:00:00', 'TTh')

declare @subject table
(
OfferNo int,
subj varchar(10),
description varchar(200),
units int,
room varchar(20),
StudDays varchar(3),
StartTime datetime,
EndTime datetime,
Capacity int
)

INSERT INTO @subject VALUES
(101, 'IT 14', 'Software Engineering', 3, 'IT L 2', 'MWF', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', 4),
(102, 'IT 15', 'Multimedia Systems', 3, 'IT L 3', 'TTh', '17:00:00', '18:30:00', 5),
(103, 'Acctg 1', 'Intro to Accounting', 3, 'J03', 'TTh', '17:00:00', '18:30:00', 5),
(104, 'Re ed 1', 'Salvation History', 3, 'CH302', 'MWF', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', 5),
(105, 'Eng 3', 'Speech and Orators', 3, 'Speech Lab', 'MWF', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', 5)

declare @newStudID int = 48490000;
declare @newStart datetime = '08:00:00'
declare @newEnd datetime = '09:00:00'
declare @newDays varchar(3) = 'MWF'
declare @newOfferNo int = 103

INSERT INTO @enlistment 
SELECT @newStudID, @newStudID, @newOfferNo, @newStart, @newEnd, @newDays
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM @enlistment WHERE StudID = @newStudID 
and ((@newStart >= StartTime AND @newStart <= EndTime) OR  
(@newEnd <= EndTime AND @newEnd >= StartTime) OR 
(StartTime >= @newStart AND StartTime <= @newEND ) OR
(EndTime >= @newStart AND EndTime <= @newEND )) 
AND StudDays = @newDays)

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as Success
```

If you run this, it will show Success 0, because the time overlaps with an existing course.  Play around with Start and End Times.  It should always block any combination that intersects/overlaps with an existing course.

This same logic you can simply transfer to your c# (the SQL you can take verbatim).  You basically have a choice: you can either run the whole INSERT and check RowsAffected (0 if it failed to insert), or you can run e.g. SELECT OfferNo FROM Enlistment WHERE .. as a separate pre-check; if the result of this is an empty result set, then you can go ahead and insert; if it returns something you can give a message pointing out that it conflicts with the given course number.  Of the two, the second is probably more friendly!

ADDENDUM

BTW In the above example, I am assuming that courses are either MWF or TTh.  If you want to cope with other combinations, then it would be better again to change the table design and have Booleans to represent Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.  The check becomes a little harder(!) but it is still feasible.  Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: @Jontahan Willcock Thank you very much sir , You just solved my problem, I spend 5 hours Solving This